# Show that if the line segments between two pair of vectors $x_1,x_2$ and $y_1,y_2$ are equal, then $x_1=y_2$ and $x_2=y_2$

Tags: linear-algebra

Define the *half-open line segment* between the ordered pair of vectors $\langle x_1,x_2\rangle$ to be the set $(x_1,x_2]= \{y:y=(1-t)x_1+tx_2, 0<t\leq 1\}$

**I want to show that if $(x_1,x_2]=(y_1,y_2]$ then $x_1=y_1 $and $ x_2=y_2$.**

I can show the following:

If  $[x_1,x_2]=[y_1,y_2]$, where $[x_1,x_2]:= \{y:y=(1-t)x_1+tx_2, 0 \leq t \leq 1\}$, and $x_1\neq y_1$ (and also $x_1\neq y_2$??) then $x_1\in [y_1,y_2]$ and thus $x_1=(1-t)y_1+ty_2$ where $t\in (0,1)$. Now since $y_1,y_2\in [x_1,x_2] $ rewriting them in terms of $x_1$ and $x_2$ this leads to an equation of the form

$\frac{(1-\lambda_1)x_1}{\lambda_2}=x_2$.

This can only be true if $x_1,x_2$ are linearly dependent, and thus not generally true. But more than this I'm not able to show.

---

I can show that both $(x_1,x_2]$ and $[x_1,x_2]$ are convex sets, but I'm not able to use this in any argument. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a bit of topology:

If $(x_1, x_2] = (y_1, y_2]$, then their closures are also equal:

$$[x_1, x_2] = \overline{(x_1, x_2]} = \overline{(y_1, y_2]} = [y_1, y_2]$$

Therefore

$$\{x_1\} = [x_1, x_2] \setminus (x_1, x_2] = [y_1, y_2] \setminus (y_1, y_2] = \{y_1\}$$

so $x_1 = y_1$.

If $x_2 \ne y_2$, then the set $(x_1, x_2] \setminus \{x_2\}$ would be path-connected, but the set $(y_1, y_2] \setminus \{x_2\}$ wouldn't be. Therefore, it must be $x_2 = y_2$.